# Is it possible a client receives half of the message following another whole message?

Tags: tcp, buffer, protocols

If I have a message protocol over TCP that looks like "|SIZE|TYPE|DATA" can my read buffer (in fact my data stream) look like this (due an error):

|SIZE|TYPE|DATA|**SIZE|TYPE|PARTIAL DATA**|SIZE|TYPE|DATA

This would cause I read bytes from 3. message into 2. Can this happen and how to detect such situation?

EDIT: With "partial data" I mean that the rest of that message is lost and will never get received. Another whole message is sent after that message and it finds its way to the receiver. However, because my 2. message is not full I will read a part of 3. message into my 2. message. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can happen that you don't read an entire message. There are no messages in TCP, it is just a byte stream. The recv() method tells you how many bytes it received.

Re your edit, nothing is lost in TCP.

Comment: I edited my post. The problem I am trying to describe is not related to how many bytes I read than what do I read.

Comment: I've become paranoid lately and started to doubt in lot of things. XD Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add some control data to you message structure while you debugging you code (e.g. CRC16/32 or MD5 calculated over your data) and check it in received messages to detect errors.
2. You can store dump of your traffic with Wireshark or tcpdump. In the dump you will see the data stream. If you data in the stream has no error but you get a "partial" message, the error is in the receiving code, otherwise it's in the sending code.